# Conserving a monthly sequence in reshape in R

Tags: r, date, reshape

RI_Final

```
Names = c("Name", "29/01/1992", "29/02/1992", 
"29/03/1992", "29/04/1992", "29/05/1992", "29/06/1992", "29/07/1992", 
"29/08/1992", "29/09/1992", "29/10/1992", "29/11/1992", "29/12/1992", 
"29/01/1993", "28/02/1993", "29/03/1993", "29/04/1993", "29/05/1993", 
"29/06/1993", "29/07/1993", "29/08/1993", "29/09/1993", "29/10/1993", 
"29/11/1993", "29/12/1993", "29/01/1994", "28/02/1994", "29/03/1994", 
"29/04/1994", "29/05/1994", "29/06/1994", "29/07/1994", "29/08/1994", 
"29/09/1994", "29/10/1994", "29/11/1994", "29/12/1994", "29/01/1995", 
"28/02/1995", "29/03/1995", "29/04/1995", "29/05/1995", "29/06/1995", 
"29/07/1995", "29/08/1995", "29/09/1995", "29/10/1995", "29/11/1995", 
"29/12/1995", "29/01/1996", "29/02/1996", "29/03/1996", "29/04/1996", 
"29/05/1996", "29/06/1996", "29/07/1996", "29/08/1996", "29/09/1996", 
"29/10/1996", "29/11/1996", "29/12/1996", "29/01/1997", "28/02/1997", 
"29/03/1997", "29/04/1997", "29/05/1997", "29/06/1997", "29/07/1997", 
"29/08/1997", "29/09/1997", "29/10/1997", "29/11/1997", "29/12/1997", 
"29/01/1998", "28/02/1998", "29/03/1998", "29/04/1998", "29/05/1998", 
"29/06/1998", "29/07/1998", "29/08/1998", "29/09/1998", "29/10/1998", 
"29/11/1998", "29/12/1998", "29/01/1999", "28/02/1999", "29/03/1999", 
"29/04/1999", "29/05/1999", "29/06/1999", "29/07/1999", "29/08/1999", 
"29/09/1999", "29/10/1999", "29/11/1999", "29/12/1999", "29/01/2000", 
"29/02/2000", "29/03/2000", "29/04/2000", "29/05/2000", "29/06/2000", 
"29/07/2000", "29/08/2000", "29/09/2000", "29/10/2000", "29/11/2000", 
"29/12/2000"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>)
```

I have a DF I want to reshaped to Panel DF this was my solution

```
reshaped.RI_Final<-  reshape(RI_Final, 
  direction="long", 
  varying=list(names(RI_Final)[2:290]),
  v.names="Value",

  timevar="Month")
```

the variables from 2:290 are a monthly sequence from 02/1992 to 12/2015 in my solution I can't find in Month Column the dates.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data, e.g. by using `dput(RI_Final)` or a sub-sample, we can't tell what's going on.

Comment: I attatched the RI (R.S.)

Comment: Can you check that this is the correct output of `dput(RI_Final)`? I should be able to just copy/paste the data, but It produces an error when I run it.